# Add scrollbar to a panel inside a jtabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane, null-layout-manager

I´d try to add a scrollbar to a pane that is inside a jtabbedPane but nothing works, hope someone can help.

This is what i had try:

```
        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel_3);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(643, 900));

        tabbedPane.add(scroll, "test");
        panel_3.setLayout(null);
```

[Demostration IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL5Mw.png)

Comment: Do you call panel3.add(tabbedPane); somewhere?

Comment: yes i did! but the problem is no scrollbar is shown!

Comment: There are two problems in that uncompilable code snippet. 1) `scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(643, 900));` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) `panel_3.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). **More general advice:** For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).